# former or formerly on name change

Tags: adverbs, ellipsis

I have a difference of opinion with some colleagues of mine. We want to express a changed name of a person with refering to the previous name. I wrote it like this:

> Steve Smith (formerly Steve Jones)

My colleagues say that it should be `"former"`. I think it should be `"formerly"` because it's short for `"formerly named"`. To me I would use `"former"` only in cases like:

> Barack Obama, former president

Am I right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. But what it's short for is "formerly known as," as in [The Artist Formerly Known as Prince](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_(musician)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three of the following are correct:

> The former Steve Jones (now Steve Smith)…
>   Steve Smith (the former Steve Jones)…
>   Steve Smith (formerly Steve Jones)…

The first two choices use the word "former" as an adjective.

As KSHuang mentioned in the comments, the third choice's "formerly" is short for "formerly known as".

If the person is a woman who got married, so she changed her name from her birth name to her married name, you can use a fourth option:

> Sally Smith (*née* Jones)…

*[Née](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/nee)* is the feminine French word for "born as".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are correct, and here is why:

[Former](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/former) is an adjective, which modifies a noun. The former supervisor was brutal.

[Formerly](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/formerly) is an adverb, which modifies a verb. He had formerly been assigned to the night shift.